# Парсер возвращает строку,а нужно массив

Tags: php, mysql, sql, парсер, backend

Написал парсер:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

include_once __DIR__ . '/phpQuery.php';
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument(file_get_contents('https://www.litmir.me/bs'));

$author = $doc->find('span[itemprop="author"]');
$data = (pq($author)->text());
print_r($data);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы значения, которые возвращает парсер, записывались по одному в бд, однако он пытается записать все целиком: [image: База данных]

Я уже понял, что парсер возвращает строку, а не массив, поэтому и записать каждое значение по отдельности не выходит.
Могу ли я записывать значения из парсера как элементы массива, чтобы потом их перебрать и записать в бд?

Буду очень благодарен за любую инфу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно циклом проходиться по каждому эл-ту и записывать его в массив

```
$data = [];
foreach($dom->find("span[itemprop='author']") as $author) {
    $data[] = pq($author)->text();
}
```